# How to write an async for database function?

Tags: django, asynchronous, django-channels

I have a function that is written as so:

```py
@database_sync_to_async     
def list_values(self):         
    return list(   
        Model.objects.all().select_related("related").order('date')[::-1]         
    )
```

I'm trying to rewrite to work with an async for loop `async for value in self.list_values`. However my current attempt

```py
async def list_values(self):         
    return ( 
        Model.objects.all().select_related("related").order('date')[::-1]         
    )
```

Gives me an error `'async for' requires an object with __aiter__ method, got coroutine`. I've also played around with adding await and yield, etc. but to no end. Any suggestions and an explanation of how I'm thinking about this wrong?